# Weird buzzy static on headphones only

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

I've been having this issue for about a month now. Every time I plug in headphones or speakers into the audio jack I get this weird static noise. I can still hear the music and audio, but when I pause it there's this noticeable buzzy or static sound.

I've Googled it a bunch of times and tried a few different methods to solve it. There's are the ones I tried last time:

- Some people suggest using AlsaMixer to fix it, but I don't seem to have all of the options the solution recommends.
- Entering `pulseaudio --check`, `pulseaudio --k`, `pulseaudio --D` turns off the sound, but when I unplug & replug it's back to the same issue.
- Entering `killall speech-dispatcher`, which does nothing.

Any idea what else I could try?

System details:

- Dell Laptop: XPS 13 9350
- Operating System: Ubuntu 19.04 disco (x86-64)
- Cinnamon Version: 4.0.9
- Linux Kernel: 5.0.0-32-generic
- Processor: Intel Core i5-6200U CPU @ 2.30GHz x 2
- Memory: 7.7 GiB
- Hard Drives: 125.1 GB
- Graphics Card: Intel Corporation Skylake GT2 (HD Graphics 520)
- Service Tag: 1QCB562
- Express Service Code: 3769578218

https://www.dell.com/support/home/ca/en/cabsdt1/product-support/servicetag/0-SGpLZEhQVlpnTVFjYkU1VjRFemNQdz090/overview

EDIT: I'm starting to think it might be a physical or hardware problem. I tried a USB pair of headphones & there was no static at all.

It's weird that my audio-jack headphones have a problem, but plugging audio-jack speakers in is fine. Also messing around with AlsaMixer sometimes fixes it, but maybe that's just coincidence.

Answer (score 1):

I know you have mentioned Alsamixer solutions. But just in case. Have you tried to mute the Headphones mic (if any, all) and/or disable loopback on ALSAmixer? There are many threads on XPS 13 and 15 on this matter (and [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Dell/comments/4j1zz4/headphones_have_static_noise_with_ubuntu_1604_on/) is a Reddit on it too)

Comment: There are 2 options for Headphone, and 1 option called "Headset Mi". Which one is the mic? Also there does not seem to be any option for loopback.

Comment: These are the options in Alsamixer; the (M) denotes it can be muted. ---Master (M) ---Headphone (M) ---Headphone ---Speaker (M) ---PCM ---Mic MuteL ---S/PDIF (M) ---S/PDIF 1 (M) ---S/PDIF 2 (M) ---S/PIDF 3 (M) ---S/PDIF 4 (M) ---AutoMute ---Headset Mi ---Internal M

Comment: Try muting anything related to a microphone.